# How can I reduce the code by styling <a> element, instead of creating a new <div>?

Tags: css

I want to style Ionicons, so when you hover social network icon, it gets its color:

```
        <div class="col span-1-of-2">
            <ul class="social-icons">
                <li><a href="#"><div class="facebook"><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div class="twitter"><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div class="google"><ion-icon name="logo-google"></ion-icon></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div class="instagram"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon></div></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Is there a way styling each element, without creating an individual div for each social network?

```
.facebook:hover,
.facebook:active {
    color: #1877f2;
}

.twitter:hover,
.twitter:active {
    color: #1da1f2;
}

.google:hover,
.google:active {
    color: #ea4335;
}

.instagram:hover,
.instagram:active {
    color: #c32aa3;
}
```

Comment: Put the class on the `<a>` tag and remove the div?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it didn't work. Only worked with !imortant tag. Any way to find what's causing the problem?

Comment: If `!important` worked then there are other styles that are affecting those elements (since color is inherited). Could you show us the other styles applied? Could be as simple as increasing the specificity of your selector.

Comment: I noticed that this has got impact: .social-icons li a:link,
`.social-icons li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;    
    font-size: 180%;
    border: 0;
    color: #888;
    transition: color 0.2s;
}`

When I delete the color property, then I can change the hover color.

Comment: it's specificity issue, check my updated answer

Comment: If you can't use CSS custom properties like Temani's answer, which I'd recommend to go with if possible - you can just write your selectors to increase the specificity, like `.social-icons li a.facebook:hover`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline styles combined with CSS variables:

```css
.social-icons li a:hover,
.social-icons li a:active {
  color: var(--c);
}

/* Irrelevant styles*/
.social-icons {
  font-size:30px;
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
}
.social-icons a {
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col span-1-of-2">
  <ul class="social-icons">
    <li>
      <a href="#" style="--c:#1877f2">
        <ion-icon name="logo-facebook">A</ion-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" style="--c:#1da1f2">
        <ion-icon name="logo-twitter">A</ion-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" style="--c:#ea4335">
        <ion-icon name="logo-google">A</ion-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" style="--c:#c32aa3">
        <ion-icon name="logo-instagram">A</ion-icon>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```